# How to modify Kubeflow source code before deploying it with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I encountered the same issue as in https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/6014 with my Kubeflow app. The fix is very simple (just a type casting), then I would like to fix it myself and redeploy Kubeflow.

The problem is that I am running a k3s cluster on my local machine where I have installed [Kubeflow bundle via Juju](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/install). Then, I cannot change the source code.

How to modify Kubeflow source code before deploying it with Kubernetes?
Should I use the manifest installation https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests#installation ? or a totally different method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed in the last version of the manifests, then I have finally installed kubeflow directly from the [manifests](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests).

But still I am in touch with one Kubeflow developer, I will post here the right way to do modify/deploy if interested.

Answer (score -1):

You got to check out their Github repo. Make changes and use kustomize to install like explained in their wiki. If you check the example folder you can see that it points to all other component folders.

https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests#install-with-a-single-command

One another hack could be, just look for the controllers in Kubernetes eg., deployments created for kubeflow, then modify them; works only if your changes are only related to Kubernetes resource definitions. I suggest going with the first option above for a clean development experience, and hey, that way can you contribute back to the kubeflow project as well, if you changes will benefit others.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean and I also would go for the first solution.

However Kubeflow is a github organization that has two repos: https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow and https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests

I have to do the fix in a file located in the first repo:
https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/crud-web-apps/jupyter/backend/apps/common/form.py

while kustomize must be used on the second repo (kubeflow/manifests).

Then I don't see how the two repos are linked together? How can I change the sources in kubeflow/kubeflow and deploy it with k8s?

Comment: I would strongly recommend contacting their developer community . But for a quick suggestion, once after your changes, you can build an image using docker build on https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/crud-web-apps/jupyter/Dockerfile . Then you can do edit live deployment `jupyter-web-app` or update https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/crud-web-apps/jupyter/manifests/base/deployment.yaml#L14 to point to your registry and re-run kustomize. But remember this image must be pushed to a registry which can be accessed by your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: But normally their developers can suggest their branching and tagging strategy and also provide access to their public ecr registry where you can push your development image like `public.ecr.aws/j1r0q0g6/notebooks/jupyter-web-app` and you should be able to edit, build, deploy etc very easily. Guess community is at https://github.com/kubeflow/community/tree/master/wg-notebooks